# How to sream MP4 videos from Wowza to JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, wowza

1. ) here is what I tired.

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>   <embed
>     flashvars="file=sample.mp4&streamer=rtmp://[my_server_ip]:1935/vod&provider=rtmp"
>     allowfullscreen="true"
>     allowscriptaccess="always"
>     id="player1"
>     name="player1"
>     src="player.swf"
>     width="480"
>     height="270"
>   />
>
> </body>   
> </html>
> ```

When  host this file in loclahost it says "Could not load player configuration". What am i doing wrong?

2.) If the above problem got fixed how can I stream a folder of video files which is not inside wowza?

Comment: I had a problem with straming using JWPlayer on localhost. Did you try upload your code to a webserver and try it there?

Comment: ok. i'll give a try. Isnt it enough using it inside apache?

Comment: Yes you can use any server you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JW6, but your code is for JW5. In JW6, we also don't support the embed tag. You need to embed using our JS embedder (jwplayer.js). Also RTMP urls are treated as one url now, not broken up as file / streamer. We have a migration guide here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6